# Calculating time in a price list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Price list table in SQL Server 2008R2 and want to calculate the Price for a Service according to the time where the Service has been made.

```
timefrom           |timeto             |Price
--------           |------             |-----
1900-01-01 00:00:00|1900-01-01 07:00:00|20.00
1900-01-01 07:00:00|1900-01-01 19:00:00|15.00
1900-01-01 19:00:00|1900-01-02 00:00:00|20.00
```

This pricelist Shows different Price during night time starting at 19:00 and Lasting until 07.00 AM and daytime from 07:00 to 19:00.

Minutes have to be rounded up and down to quarter hours.
There is some more to take care of, such as Minimum notice Periode (@Vorlaufzeit) and if weekday of Weekend. Both conditions are met and not the Problem. My Problem is the first and the last record, where I have to round up and/or round down, which are incorrect. Both lines have 1 in the loop and should be corrected correctly in the both updates, but does not.

So, for example a Service from 2016-11-04 10:50 (rounding down to 10:45 which is 0.25 hours) to 2016-11-04 19:25 (rounded up to 19:30 which is 0.5 hours) is 0.25+8+0.5= 8.75 hours and costs 8.25*15 + 0.5*20 = 133.75.

I tried with this code, but it does not bring me the correct result. It is only the first and the last record where I have to round up or down. It is only correct, when there are full hours.

```
        DECLARE @Dauer int
    DECLARE @X int  --Loopcounter für Stunden
    declare @Y int  --Loopcounter für Tageszahler
    declare @Anfangszeit datetime
    declare @Anfangsstunde datetime
    declare @Endzeit datetime
    declare @Vorlaufzeit int  --in Minuten
    declare @ErsteZeitvon datetime
    declare @SummeAnzStunden decimal(8,2)
    declare @MinimumZeit int
    declare @ZeitvonVolleStunde int  -- aus 07:25 mach 7 Uhr
    declare @ZeitbisVolleStunde int 

    declare @AnfangsDatumZeit as datetime
    declare @EndDatumZeit as datetime 
    declare @AnfangsDatumZeitLoop as datetime
    declare @AnfangsZeitLoop as datetime
    declare @TagesZaehler int

    set @AnfangsDatumZeit = @Datumvon+@Zeitvon
    set @EndDatumZeit = @Datumbis+@Zeitbis
    set @Tageszaehler=datediff(day,@AnfangsDatumZeit, @EndDatumZeit)

    declare @t1 table ( PreisID int, AnzStunden decimal(5,2), Preis decimal(8,2), Anfangszeit datetime, Prüfzeit datetime, startzeit datetime, endezeit datetime, Vorlaufzeit int, Dauer int, PreisFT decimal(8,2), DatZeitvon datetime, DatZeitbis datetime, Tageszaehler int )

    -- Insert statements for procedure here


    set @ZeitvonVolleStunde=Datediff(hour, '00:00:00', @Zeitvon)

    set @ZeitbisVolleStunde=Datediff(minute, '00:00:00', @Zeitbis)


    set @Dauer=ceiling(Datediff(minute, @AnfangsDatumZeit, @EndDatumZeit)/60.00)  

set @Vorlaufzeit=datediff(minute,@Bestelldatum, @AnfangsDatumZeit)     


    SET @X = 0

if Datediff(minute, @AnfangsDatumZeit, @EndDatumZeit) > 360
    begin
            WHILE (@X <=@Dauer)  --z.b. 13

            begin   


                    --set @Y = datediff(day,@AnfangsDatumZeit,@AnfangsDatumZeitLoop)
                    set @Y = datediff(day,@AnfangsDatumZeit,dateadd(hour,@X, @AnfangsDatumZeit))

                    set @AnfangsDatumZeitLoop=dateadd(hour,@X, @AnfangsDatumZeit)

                    set @AnfangsZeitLoop=dateadd(hour,@X, @Zeitvon)



                            insert into @t1 ( PreisID, AnzStunden, Preis , Anfangszeit, Prüfzeit, DatZeitvon , DatZeitbis  )



                            SELECT top 1 preisID, 1, Preis, @AnfangsZeitLoop, @AnfangsDatumZeitLoop, Zeitvon,  Zeitbis

                                 FROM dbo.Mypricetable 
                                 where  SdlID=@Leistungsart   --SdlID
                                        and Wochentag=case when DATEPART(dw,@AnfangsDatumZeitLoop) < 6 then 'W' else 'S' end  --Wochentag 
                                        and @Vorlaufzeit BETWEEN Vorlaufzeitvon and Vorlaufzeitbis  --Vorlaufzeit in Minuten
                                        AND @Dauer*60 BETWEEN Dauervon AND Dauerbis   --DauerInMinuten 
                                        and @AnfangsZeitLoop between Zeitvon and  Zeitbis --sucht die von/bis Zeitgruppe
                                 order by zeitvon

            SET @X = @X + 1
            end

    --check and udate of the first record in @t1 rounding down to 15 minutes
    update @t1 set Anzstunden= Anzstunden + CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), ROUND(((datediff(minute,[dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,1), [dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,4)) + 7) / 60.00) / 25, 2) * 25)
    from @t1 c where c.Prüfzeit=(SELECT Top 1 Prüfzeit from @t1 order by Prüfzeit) 

    --check and udate of the last record in @t1 rounding up to 15 minutes
    update @t1 set Anzstunden= round(convert(decimal(5,2),datepart(minute,@EndDatumZeit)+7)/60/25,2)*25
    from @t1 c where c.Prüfzeit=(SELECT Top 1 Prüfzeit from @t1 order by Prüfzeit DESC) 


    end

    select * from @t1 order by Prüfzeit
```

Thanks your help!
Michael

Comment: Why are you using `datetime` instead of `time`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Having done similar things, the inability of `time` to express 24 hours (or more) makes ranges that cross midnight something of a nightmare to handle. Checking for `RangeStart <= Target <= RangeEnd` becomes something like `( RangeStart <= Target and Target <= RangeEnd ) or ( RangeStart > RangeEnd and ( RangeStart <= Target or Target <= RangeEnd ) )`. Not too bad if tested and hidden in a UDF, but clumsy and error prone when scattered about.

Comment: @HABO not in this case. This is just hours in a day. There are far worse problems here though, including the attempt to loop instead of write a proper query

Answer (score 0):

This code is a bit verbose, but wanted to share it with you as it produces the desired result of **133.75**

```
DECLARE @x table (
   timefrom datetime
 , timeto   datetime
 , price    decimal(14,4)
);

INSERT INTO @x (timefrom, timeto, price)
  VALUES ('1900-01-01T00:00:00', '1900-01-01T07:00:00', 20.00)
       , ('1900-01-01T07:00:00', '1900-01-01T19:00:00', 15.00)
       , ('1900-01-01T19:00:00', '1900-01-02T00:00:00', 20.00)
;

-- You should have your own, physical tally table!
DECLARE @numbers table (
   number tinyint
);
INSERT INTO @numbers (number)
SELECT DISTINCT
       number
FROM   master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE  number BETWEEN 0 AND 255
;

DECLARE @start datetime = '2016-11-04T10:50:00'
      , @end   datetime = '2016-11-04T19:25:00'
;

-- first, let's do some rounding of our inputs
DECLARE @rounded_start_time time
      , @rounded_end_time   time
;


-- Illustrate the steps to round the time to quarters... this might not be the simplest method; but it works!
/*
SELECT @start AS start
     , DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @start), 0) AS truncate_hour
     , Round(DatePart(mi, @start) / 15.0, 0) * 15 AS rounded_mins
     , DateAdd(mi, Round(DatePart(mi, @start) / 15.0, 0) * 15, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @start), 0)) AS truncate_hour_then_add_mins
;
*/

SET @rounded_start_time = DateAdd(mi, Round(DatePart(mi, @start) / 15.0, 0) * 15, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @start), 0));
SET @rounded_end_time   = DateAdd(mi, Round(DatePart(mi, @end  ) / 15.0, 0) * 15, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @end  ), 0));

PRINT 'Start: ' + Format(@rounded_start_time, 'HH:mm');
PRINT 'End:   ' + Format(@rounded_end_time  , 'HH:mm');

--SELECT *
--FROM   @x
--;

; WITH intervals AS (
  SELECT number * 15 AS minute_increments
       , DateAdd(mi,  number *      15, 0) AS interval_start
       , DateAdd(mi, (number + 1) * 15, 0) AS interval_end
  FROM   @numbers
  WHERE  number >= 0
  AND    number <  24 * 4 --number of 15 minute increments in a day
)
, costed_intervals AS (
  SELECT intervals.interval_start
       , intervals.interval_end
       , Cast(intervals.interval_start AS time) As interval_start_time
       , Cast(intervals.interval_end   AS time) As interval_end_time
       , x.price / 4.0 AS interval_price
  FROM   @x AS x
   INNER
    JOIN intervals
      ON intervals.interval_end   <= x.timeto
     AND intervals.interval_start >=  x.timefrom
)
, applicable_intervals AS (
  SELECT interval_start
       , interval_end
       , interval_start_time
       , interval_end_time
       , interval_price
  FROM   costed_intervals
  WHERE  interval_start_time < @rounded_end_time
  AND    interval_end_time   > @rounded_start_time
)
SELECT Sum(interval_price) AS total_price
FROM   applicable_intervals
;
```

This could use a ***lot*** of cleaning up and optimising.
It also only works when the start and end times are within the same day, among other bugs and fun stuff.

Comment: thx yr efforts! See my answer which gives me the ability to calculate over one day.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyones contribution I could find my way and corrected my Duration and the two updates.

```
Duration:
set @Dauer=datediff(hh, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @Datumvon+@Zeitvon), 0),DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @datumbis+@Zeitbis), 0)) 

Update the first record
update @t1 set Anzstunden =Anzstunden + (datediff(mi,DateAdd(mi, Round((DatePart(mi, @Zeitvon)-7) / 15.0, 0) * 15, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @Zeitvon), 0)),DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @Zeitvon), 0))/60.00) 
    -- case when CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), ROUND(((datediff(minute,[dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,1), [dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,4)) + 7) / 60.00) / 25, 2) * 25) *-1 > 0 then 
    -- CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 2), ROUND(((datediff(minute,[dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,1), [dbo].[sfRoundToHourParts](@AnfangsDatumZeit,4)) + 7) / 60.00) / 25, 2) * 25) *-1 else Anzstunden end
from @t1 c where c.Prüfzeit=(SELECT Top 1 Prüfzeit from @t1 order by Prüfzeit) 

Update the last record

--Prüft und korrigiert den LETZTEN Datensatz der @t1 auf 15 Minuten-Takt
update @t1 set Anzstunden= Anzstunden + ((datediff(mi,DateAdd(mi, Round((DatePart(mi, @Zeitbis)+7) / 15.0, 0) * 15, DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @Zeitbis), 0)),DateAdd(hh, DateDiff(hh, 0, @Zeitbis), 0))/60.00)*-1)
from @t1 c where c.Prüfzeit=(SELECT Top 1 Prüfzeit from @t1 order by Prüfzeit DESC)
```

now everything is correct.
Thx to everyone.
Michael